# Database/Webserver Alternatives

Tags: pi-2, web-server, database

I have a Rasp pi project currently in the works for a college class... Everything is going great, but I really don't feel like my Pi (2B) will be able to handle being..

1.) Appache Web Server (CSS / HTML / PHP *eww*)

2.) MySQL Server

3.) Bluetooth Scanner (Python / Bluetooth Dongle)

All at the same time. Especially since every 30 seconds the database will be hit with about 20-30 requests (1 for each bluetooth device detected), and then the web server will be using some ajax/jquery to refresh content on the current webpage every 30ish seconds.

I traditionally come from IIS servers and .Net programming and the Microsoft suite of software products (SQL server), and I'm very new to Pi / Linux software tools & products.

I feel very limited in types of server-side languages I can use due to the limited amount of web servers that support Pi devices.

---

Onto the question(s) at hand...

1.) What other alternatives do I have to web servers? I *really* like c# and vb.net. And I *really* don't like PHP. Java is *okay*

2.) What alternatives do I have to mySQL? I looked into parse.com... has anyone had any success with using that for single-paged websites?

---

I hope this question isn't *too* broad or *too* opinion based.

THANKS!

Comment: How big are the database tables? 20-30 hits sounds like a lot, but it might not be a problem if the tables are small. You could use Nginx instead of Apache, and you could try using SQLite instead of MySQL.

Comment: Not that big... 10 columns and maybe ~30 rows. I was looking into SQLite and it seemed plausible for what I am trying to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use node.js and there are databases like mongodb you can use. Don't use the node from apt-get, Raspbian is quiet bad at keeping version up to date. Try [here](http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/) instead.

Comment: Thank you, it appears that Node.Js is more lightweight and geared towards this type of use. I'll also look into mongodb.